# Overriding Backbone sync with a progress event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I'm attempting to override the Backbone `sync` function in order to listen to `progress` events. However, `xhr.upload` is undefined, so the code below isn't working. Any ideas?

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

  ...

  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {  
          var percentComplete = event.loaded/event.total;
          console.log(percentComplete);
        }
      }, false); 
    }
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
  },

  ...

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for us:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) { 
  options.beforeSend = function(xhr, settings) {
    settings.xhr = function() {          
      var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
        Math.ceil(event.loaded/event.total*100);
      }, false);
      return xhr;
    }
  }
  return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
```

Comment: Which version of jquery were you using? I tried this method, but the settings.xhr function doesn't even fire. It's defined though.